# Issues with jQuery Validate onkeyup and highlighting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, validation

I am having issues with jQuery Validate. This is the first time I have created a form using Validate and am a little confused on why some of the things are not working. I uploaded it to [JsFiddle HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/CTrujillo/32Lysw7j/) so that it does not become overwhelming on here, but they require that I add a little code so for the first issue I will include an example of what I tried below.

```
$('.awesome-form').validate({
                    onkeyup:true,
                    errorElement: 'div',
                    errorClass: 'formError',
```

1. I am trying to get it to validate onkeyup. I have tried to add onkeyup like it says in the documentation like above, but this does not do what I want it to do. The name field and the message field will not show an error until I click enter. Every now and then I can get it to appear but it is usually only after multiple clicks and submits.
2. I am having an issue with the custom highlight. For some reason it works only on the message input. essentially I would like it so that when an error occurs it will immediately turn the border-bottom to red.

Comment: I do not want to do this as I will also be validating server side and want to use the submit button for that. I want it so that onkeyup it will validate client side using the jQuery validator and then once the submit button is selected it will run a php process that validates everything and sends it in an email. This is my first time doing something like this and so if there is a better way to do it that would be great as well.

Comment: if we are talking about http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/ you misread the api documentation, onkeyup takes false or a function which validates on the event onkeyup

Comment: i second that @user993553. According to the documentation `A boolean true is not a valid value.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

                  $('.awesome-form .input-group input, textarea').focusout(function() {

                    var text_val = $(this).val();

                    if (text_val === "") {

                      $(this).removeClass('has-value');

                    } else {

                      $(this).addClass('has-value');

                    }

                  });

                });

                $(function() {
                  $.validator.setDefaults({
                    highlight: function(element) {
                      $(element)
                        .closest('.formInput')
                        .addClass('errorHighlight');
                    },
                    unhighlight: function(element) {
                      $(element)
                        .closest('.formInput')
                        .removeClass('errorHighlight');
                    }
                  });
                  $('.awesome-form').validate({
                    errorElement: 'div',
                    errorClass: 'formError',
                    errorContainer: '#errorPanel',
                    errorLabelContainer: '#errorPanel ul',
                    onkeyup:function(element) {
                   
                      $(element).valid();
                    },
                    wrapper: 'li',
                    rules: {
                      name: {
                        required: true
                      },
                      email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                      },
                      message: {
                        required: true
                      }
                    },
                    messages: {
                      name: {
                        required: 'Please include at least a first name'
                      },
                      email: {

                        required: 'Please include your email address',
                        email: 'Invalid email address'
                      },
                      message: {
                        required: 'Please include a short message'
                      }
                    }
                  });
                });
```

```css
.chosenContact {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.chosenContact p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
label input {
  display: none;
}
label input[type="radio"]:checked + img {
  background: red;
  border: solid 4px red;
}
input,
textarea {
  background: none;
  border: solid 2px #232323;
  color: #232323;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: inline-block;
}
input:focus,
input:active,
textarea:focus,
textarea:active {
  outline: none;
}
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
textarea {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #232323;
  min-width: 300px;
}
input[type="text"]..errorHighlight,
input[type="email"].errorHighlight,
textarea.errorHighlight {
  width: 170px;
  background-color: red;
  max-height: 70px;
}
input[type="submit"]:active {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  border: red;
}
.input-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.input-group input,
textarea {
  padding: 15px 0px;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
}
.errorHighlight {
  border: none;
  background-color: red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
.input-group label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0px;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-family: "Georgia", "Cambria", "Times New Roman", "Times", serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #999;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.15s ease-out 0s;
}
.input-group input:focus + label,
.input-group input.has-value + label,
.input-group textarea:focus + label,
.input-group textarea.has-value + label {
  top: -10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #aaa;
}
.input-group-submit {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="contactUs">

    <form class="awesome-form" name="contactForm" action="phpScripts/contactForm.php" method="post">

      <div class="contactWho">

        <label class="chosenContact">
          <input type="radio" name="who" value="Boss" checked>
          <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
          <p class="contactStaffName">Boss Man</p>

        </label>

        <label class="chosenContact">
          <input type="radio" name="who" value="staff1">
          <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
          <p class="contactStaffName">Staff Member 1</p>
        </label>

        <label class="chosenContact">
          <input type="radio" name="who" value="staff2">
          <img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100" alt="">
          <p class="contactStaffName">Staff Member 2</p>
        </label>

      </div>

      <div class="sayWhat">
        <div class="nameAndEmail">

          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="formInput" type="text" name="name">
            <label class="formLabel">Your Full Name</label>
          </div>

          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="formInput" type="email" name="email">
            <label class="formLabel">Your Email Address</label>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
          <textarea class="formInput" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
          <label class="formLabel">How Can I Help You?</label>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group-submit">
          <input type="submit" value="Contact Us">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>

    <div id="errorPanel">
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! this was exactly what I needed it to do. I had to do some changes to get my second issue worked out but this was great for getting it to validate immediately. Is the .valid another part of the jQuery Validate plugin?